# Unity3D using OnTriggerStay

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm using the event OnTriggerStay2D to destroy an object, the reason i'm using this instead of OnTriggerEnter2D is because i'm dragging the object using the touchscreen, and i want to destroy it after it is released, the problem i have is that OntriggerStay2D is not always called, so sometimes the object is not destroyed after it is released and it has to be moved again to work, i've read the docummentation from Unity

> OnTriggerStay is called almost all the frames for every Collider other that is touching the trigger.

```
public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
        if (gameObject.tag == other.tag) {

            Destroy (other.gameObject);

    }
}
```

I would like to know if there's any way to call OntriggerStay2D everytime i release the object. 
Thanks.

***Edit
Dragging code***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Drag : MonoBehaviour {

        private bool draggingItem = false;
        private GameObject draggedObject;
        private Vector2 touchOffset;

        void Update ()
        {
            if (HasInput)
            {
                DragOrPickUp();
            }
            else
            {
                if (draggingItem)
                    DropItem();
            }
        }

        Vector2 CurrentTouchPosition
        {
            get
            {
                Vector2 inputPos;
                inputPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                return inputPos;
            }
        }

        private void DragOrPickUp()
        {

            var inputPosition = CurrentTouchPosition;

            if (draggingItem)
            {

                draggedObject.transform.position = inputPosition + touchOffset;

            }
            else
            {

                RaycastHit2D[] touches = Physics2D.RaycastAll(inputPosition, inputPosition, 0.5f);
                if (touches.Length > 0)
                {
                    var hit = touches[0];
                    if (hit.transform != null && hit.rigidbody != null)
                    {
                        draggingItem = true;
                        draggedObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                        touchOffset = (Vector2)hit.transform.position - inputPosition;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool HasInput
        {
            get
            {

                return Input.GetMouseButton(0);
            }
        }

        public void DropItem()
        {
            draggingItem = false;     

        }

    }
```

Comment: What does `OnTriggerStay2D` have to do with dragging object?

Comment: I'm dragging the object to collide to another one, but i don't want to destroy it when they collide, i want to destroy it when i release it if they are still touching.

Comment: That makes sense now. Please add your drag code too. That will help give you an answer.

Comment: I edited the question, i added the dragging code.

Comment: You could just perform a RayCast, after you released the object. So you dont have to use the OnColliderStay Method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using `OnTriggerStay2D` for this. You can use a boolean variable that you set to true and false in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` function.

```
bool isTouching = false;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Entered");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("YourOtherObject"))
    {
        isTouching = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Exited");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("YourOtherObject"))
    {
        isTouching = false;
    }
}
```

You can now check the `isTouching` variable when the object is released.

```
if(isTouching){
....
}
```

---

Note that I suggest you abandon your current code that uses Raycast and `Input.GetMouseButton(0);` since you are using this on mobile devices too. You should be using Unity's new EventSystem for this since it is made to be mobile friendly too.

Since you are using 2D collider, see **#7** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects/41392130#41392130) answer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37835798/3785314) is a complete example of how to drag a Sprite with the new EventSystem. Combine that with the answer above and you get a much more better solution.

Comment: Thanks, Just by removing the OnTriggerStay2D and using the boolean as you said works perfectly, but i'm looking into your recommendation to improve it, but thank you very much, your solution really works.

Comment: Nice. Glad I was able to help and you definitely use that EventSystem I mentioned.